# The positive real number at which is the derivative of the Poisson density equal to 0

Tags: function, derivative, maple, poisson

I want to find the extreme of the Poisson density function as a smooth curve of the Poisson density.
For that I need to obtain the unique positive numerical value where is the derivative of the Poisson density equal to 0.

With this:[image]
I get only the number -0.4276 which is not >0.

The following plots nicely the appropriate curves but do not give the numerical extreme.
Here, x is to be thought as the parameter $\lambda$.
This extreme value should be approximately as big as $x$ which is E(X) but not exactly the same.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't inform `fsolve` that you wanted a positive root.

```
restart;
ee := add(k*x^k*exp(-x)/k!,x=2..2):
dee := diff(ee,k):

fsolve(dee,k=0..10);

      2.479687450

plot({ee,dee}, k=0..10);
```

[image]

This also works here:

```
fsolve(dee,k=0..infinity);

      2.479687450
```

Comment: Dear Acer, how do I make Maple to find **both now symbolic** as opposed to numeric solutions with k<0 and k>0 ?